# Statsmodel logit with sample weights

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

Using sklearn I can consider sample weights in my model, like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=w_train)
```

Is there some clever way to consider sample weights also in the Logit method of `statsmodel.api`?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit = sm.Logit(y, X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a way of using sample weights which requires a little more work than just using a single argument, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572053/9435355).